# Dim StartIndex as integer Step

Tags: vb.net

Code: This code works in reverse, from -1 to 0. how do I make it work from 0 to -1? I don't want it to work the other way around, and I want it to work normally.

```
Dim StartIndex = TxtBoxIntDrawsX.Lines.Length - 1
For i = StartIndex To 0 Step -1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Dim lengthOfX As Integer = 10
```

Reverse mode:

```
For i As Integer = lengthOfX To 0 Step -1
     Console.WriteLine(i.ToString)
Next
```

Normal mode:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To lengthOfX
     Console.WriteLine(i.ToString)
Next
```

But, in your case -1 is as result of `TxtBoxIntDrawsX.Lines.Length – 1` where probably `TxtBoxIntDrawsX.Lines.Length` is 0 (there is no lines)

Comment: Should be `lengthOfX - 1`, otherwise you'll get an index-out-of-bounds-exception.

Comment: Not in this case as there is not array bounded with this length (is just an example). Take a try if you get an error :). Was only to explain the context

Comment: He will most probably use `i` as index in the `TxtBoxIntDrawsX.Lines` array.

Comment: in my example is not "TxtBoxIntDrawsX.Lines" :).

Comment: Your example uses `lengthOfX`. We don't know what `X` is, but it is either a 1-based thing or a 0-based thing. 1-based: `For i As Integer = 1 To lengthOfX`, 0-based: `For i As Integer = 0 To lengthOfX - 1`. Otherwise (as in your example) it will loop `lengthOfX + 1` times.

Comment: Let's say I understand, but how can I start the length from 1? because it is preset every time (the first line of the textbox is 0, well how do I make that 0 actually 1?

Comment: @FatirRizky If you have an empty line you can use Continue For otherwise you can change i=1 instead of i=0.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes LengthOfX = 10 is supposed lengthOfX = TxtBoxIntDrawsX.Lines.Length – 1 as OP wrote above where TxtBoxIntDrawsX.Lines.Length is supposed to be 11

Comment: If `TxtBoxIntDrawsX.Lines.Length` is 0, you cannot access the array items. In this case assign it a single line with `TextBox1.Text = " "` (add at least one space, an empty string will not work).